# How to get URL parameter in angular 10+ from a component that's not a router-outlet?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm trying to get a URL GET parameter named 'loc' when visiting `localhost:4200/?loc=en_LSM_US`. The method's logic is that if the loc parameter is not sent to the actual page, then the locale will be calculated.

I'm trying to get the parameter using `this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('loc');` but since the actual component is not a router outlet, the route is null.

The `appComponent` looks like this:

```
<body>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</body>
```

Here's the code of `<app-footer>`:

```
private loc: string[] = [];

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private http: HttpClient
) { }

async ngOnInit() {
  await this.getLoc();
}

private async getLoc() {
  var country: string | any;
  var locStr: string | null = await this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('loc');

  if (locStr == null || locStr == '' ) { // There's no loc in URL
    console.log(locStr);
    if (navigator.language.includes('-')) { // navigator.language ~ 'es-MX'
      var locale: string[] = navigator.language.split('-')
      this.loc = [locale[0], '', locale[1]]
    } else { // navigator.language ~ 'es'
      country = await this.http.get("https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com/geolocate/")
      .pipe(map((json: any): 
        Object => {
          return (json['alpha2'] as string)
        })).toPromise();
      this.loc = [navigator.language, '', country]
    }
  } else { // There's loc in URL
    this.loc = locStr.split('_')
  }
  console.log(this.loc)
}
```

The first `console.log(locStr)` outputs `null`, and the last `console.log(this.loc)` outputs my locale using the API or `navigator.language`, although the URL has a different locale parameter `localhost:4200/?loc=en_LSM_US`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Location` from `@angular/common`, you can get the current path using `Location.path()`.

And with `HttpParams` from `@angular/common/http`, you can parse the http parameters from a string using `new HttpParams({ fromString: "string" })`.

So, doing:

```
constructor(
  private Location:Location
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(new HttpParams({ fromString: this.Location.path()}))
}
```

should print in your webconsole something like: `/current?param=value&etc=0`, where `/current` would be your actual route and any parameters would after the `?`. So just sanitizing the string eliminating the chars from 0 to `?` and then passing the string to `HttpParams` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

async and await are to be used with promises. Your `http.get` returns an `observable`

Since you want to go with `await` and `async` you should switch to promises and also not subscribe to the observable

So your code will be

```
private async getLoc() {
    var country: string | any;
    var locStr: string | null = await this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('loc');

    if (locStr == null || locStr == '' ) { // There's no loc in URL
      console.log(locStr);
      if (navigator.language.includes('-')) { // navigator.language ~ 'es-MX'
        var locale: string[] = navigator.language.split('-')
        this.loc = [locale[0], '', locale[1]]
      } else { // navigator.language ~ 'es'



 country = await this.http.get("https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com/geolocate/")
        .pipe(map((json: any): 
            Object => {
              return (json['alpha2'] as string)
            })).toPromise();
        this.loc = [navigator.language, '', country]
      }


 }
    } else { // There's loc in URL
      this.loc = locStr.split('_')
    }
    console.log(this.loc)
}
```

Comment: The compiler continues executing everything without waiting for `await this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('loc');` at line 3, therefore the following `if` will continue to be true when it shouldn't be.

Comment: I've edited the question with the correction in your answer, but still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Dialvive where is the code that you pass that url information? Can you please edit the question and add the relevant code?

Comment: @Dialvive `await this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('loc');` you don't need await there. It should be available when the component has loaded.

Comment: @Dialvive I think that you either set or read that loc query parameter wrong. Post the code that passes that query parameter from some other html or component. There should be the mistake

Comment: All of the code is already posted, `loc` is declared as an empty array at the beginning of the code block. I thought using `await` would make the compiler pause until `this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('loc');` returns something, but it doesn't. The URL information is read from within the method when the component is loaded, it's read from the URL, it's not passed from anywhere else.

Comment: don't you think that somewhere you should set that 'loc' in route.snapshot before getting it? How would that `this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get` work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230910/discussion-between-dialvive-and-boug).

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to await an observable. that's not going to work.
better use RXJS:

```
private getLoc(): Observable<Array<string>> {
    return this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
        switchMap(({ loc }) => {
            if (loc) {
                return of(locStr.split('-'))
            } else {
                const lang = navigator.language;
                const isLangIncludeDash = lang.includes('-');

                if (isLangIncludeDash) {
                    const langArr = lang.split('');
                    return of([langArr[0], '', langArr[1]]);
                } else {
                    const api$ = this.http.get("https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com/geolocate/");
                    return api$.pipe(map(({ alpha2 }) => [lang, '', alpha2]));
                }
            }
        })
    );
}
```

then subscribe wherever (and unsubscribe ondestroy)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getLoc().subscribe(result => this.loc = result);
}
```